# Putting a ASP.NET MVC web site in a subfolder

Tags: asp.net-mvc

For a shared test environment I need to place an ASP.NET MVC 1.0 web application in a subfolder. So the URL to the web applications start page will look something like http://192.168.100.1/webapp1/.

Is this possible at all or must it always reside in the root?

Answer (score 2):

Er yes- just create a virtual directory. Let us know if you want any further info (I suggest you try Google first though).

Comment: The links doesn't work and the site loses its css (yes, I use relative urls to the css files and the anchor helper to create the links). So do you have any suggestions how to fix that?

Comment: Use Fiddler to see where the Web browser is requesting. I always use something like this (Url.Content) <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js")%>"></script>, cause it always works.

Comment: Richard is exactly right. The problem is not that MVC is somehow incompatible with a virtual directory. The problem is that *the views you have written* contain absolute paths, and absolute paths are not compatible with deployment to a virtual directory. You need to fix your views, in exactly the way specified in Richard's comment.